# Django Unique on ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a private messaging system between users. I created two models. One is "Message" which contains messages and another one is "Conversation" which contains messages just between two users. I want to head off create duplicate conversations. For example i created a conversation between user1 and user2 and this conversation's ID is "5" then i created another one conversation again between user1 and user2 and it's ID is "6". That's bad for me. There must just one conversation between same users.

When i try "**unique=True**" i'm getting an error as "**api.Conversation.participants: (fields.E330) ManyToManyFields cannot be unique.**"

**models.py**

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, unique=True)



class Message(models.Model):
     sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_query_name='s')
     reciepent = models.ManyToManyField(User)
     conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     msg_content = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
     sendtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     ordering = ["-sendtime"]
```

Comment: But can't your `Conversation` have multiple `User`s as suggested by the `ManyToManyField`? If so then the unique constraint doesn't make much sense. If a conversation can have only two users then your modelling is incorrect and the `ManyToManyField` should be from `User` to itself (`self`)

Comment: Yes, a conversation can have only two users like User1 and User2, User3 and User5... But that must be unique. If there is a conversation between User1 and User2 you can't create a conversation again between User1 and User2. I don't want to duplicate user pairs in conversations.